# failed to stuff "ctrl-a H" to a screen session

Tags: scripting, gnu-screen

I need to toggle logging from outside of a detached screen session. Interactively you do this by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>.

Their octal codes are `\001` and `\110`. ([source](http://www.unix-manuals.com/refs/misc/ascii-table.html))

What I tried:

```
$ screen -S test
```

then from other terminal I tried to push these codes to the screen:

```
$ screen -S test -X stuff $'\\001\\110\\r'
```

However instead of the expected `Appending to logfile screenlog.0` I got `bash: h: command not found`

Please tell me how to push 'Ctrl-a H' to a detached screen session.

Comment: Outh of curiosity... Why don't you reattach to the detached session and press ctrl-a H?

Comment: I'm running many services in screen sessions over multiple machines and I'm managing them using a wrapper script that can be called remotely.

Comment: According to the `screen` man page, `stuff` sends the string to the the input buffer of the current window, i.e. to the controlling process that is running in this window. If I understand correctly, this is not what you want.

Comment: Have you tried -d -m? according to the manual this creates a new session but doesn't attach to it, which is what I presume you are looking for. Create a new screen detached, name it and send som commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've injected the characters `Ctrl+A`, `H` and `Return` into the application (bash) running in the Screen window. The string that is passed to `stuff` is not parsed for Screen escapes.

`screen -S test -X log on` seems to work, or `screen -S test -X log` to toggle as you want.

Comment: I know that saying thank you is against the forum policy... but thank you :)